# Call super inside asynchronous callback

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6

I'm currently trying to run an asynchronous function with a callback inside of my constructor. I then need to get data from that callback and use it when creating an instance of the class. My code currently looks like this:

```
class Foo extends Bar {
    constructor(data) {
        someAsyncCall((response) => {
            data.a = response;
            super(data);
        });
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: where is your super defined??

Comment: @P.K. super is an ES6 keyword..https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super

Comment: By the time the async call is initiated, the parent class has already been constructed, and it's far too late to call `super`. There is a reason that `super` must be the first call in a constructor (or at least be called before `this` is used).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion I wouldn't do it inside the constructor. Use the Q library and another helper class as a data access layer.

```
HelperClass.getFooById(id)
    .then(function (data) {
        return new Foo(data);
    })
```

The `getFooById` method would use `Q.defer()` and would call `Q.resolve(data)` once the data is resolved.

If you do it inside of the constructor you can never create an instance of that class without making a request, even if you have the data already.

Q Library: https://github.com/kriskowal/q

Comment: I don't know that I would say "definitely don't do it inside the constructor". It's meant to be able to be used that way, and MDN docs give examples.

Comment: Could you post a link to those examples? I'm curious as to why they would recommend doing it that way.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super